To publish previous papers in books
People are invited to publish in new books papers that were already published in SCI indexed journals. Some say it depends on the agreement and if there's transferred exclusive rights. Is it usually allowed by SCI indexed journals to publish their previous papers elsewhere say in new books?

Why would one want to do this?

why would feynman want to do this?

Do you mean an actual, honest invitation or just the usual, countless junk invites for junk books based on junk scraping?

@MisterMiyagi can't tell if they are honest or not. Sometimes they come reach out after  we submit a paper

If you hold copyright then you can publish or republish. But if you have given a broad license to the world, then so can others. And CC-BY requires only citation.
The author pages at SCI suggest that the author retains copyright, but the open science aspects suggest that a broad license is given.
The value to SCI comes at the beginning when authors cover the costs of publication. They don't expect to be "sole providers" of the information.
But if you are getting requests to republish, take care that you are dealing with someone reputable. Odd, but you can give your copyright to someone else after publishing open access, but the license previously given is still valid and the new copyright owner can't withdraw it.
And, I'd suggest not following up with anyone who later asks you for money to republish.

sorry I still don't get the answer. So the answer for SCI indexed journals is: it depends?
